# C# The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, video, ffmpeg

I'm making a Video sharing application(the likes of youtube) for my bachelor degree(the project is done in asp.net web forms)
And i want to convert any video the user uploads to mp4.For this i'm using the Nreco ffmpeg wrapper for asp.

I'm doing all this locally and this project is not going live.

The video conversion is done in a separate thread.

```
protected void Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//File Uploads to Server
Thread t1 = new Thread(
unused => compressVideo(Video_Path, Final_Path,User_id)
);
t1.Start();
}

public static void compressVideo(string Video_Path, string Final_Path,string UID)
{
    var ffMpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
    ffMpeg2.ConvertProgress += (o, args) =>
        {
            //SignalR calls.Doing this to update the ui
        };

    ffMpeg.ConvertMedia(Video_Path, Final_Path, NReco.VideoConverter.Format.mp4);
}
```

First time i did this it all worked fine,not a single problem.
Two weeks late,after not modifying this page,i try it again and the application throws this exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception'
>   occurred in NReco.VideoConverter.dll
>
> Additional information: The specified executable is not a valid
>   application for this OS platform.

on the line:

```
ffMpeg.ConvertMedia(Video_Path, Final_Path, NReco.VideoConverter.Format.mp4);
```

If i call the `ffMpeg.ConvertMedia()`,the exception is not thrown and the code works as expected.So im guessing it has something to do with threads.But that's not all.
After messing around with the code trying to solve this and not succeeding i revert back to the original code.In a last attempt i try it again(with the original code) and the application gave the build error.

> attempted to access an unloaded appdomain.

Any modification i did to the code was ignored and i was always getting that error when compiling.
After taking a five minutes break to calm down, i try it again.It magically fixed its self.The build error was gone and even the conversion was working.

But the dream didn't last long.After a few minutes the conversion thread started throwing the same exception again.
I was not able to replicate the same result.

My experience and knowledge with asp.net web forms and web design in general are fairly low,so please keep the answers as simple as possible.

Comment: Are you currently getting the unloaded appdomain build error, or the Win32Exception? If it's the Win32Exception, have you changed your working environment in any way? (e.g. are you using a different computer, a different OS, etc?)

Comment: Currently i'm getting the Win32Exception.I haven't changed the OS nor the computer,the project is in the exact same place from the start(if that matters).I added a couple of References and nuget packages to the project but i dont think that affects it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uninstalling the NReco.VideoConverter NuGet package and reinstalling it? The code you have works - it seems to be a problem with the package library that might be solved by a reinstallation.

Answer (score 0):

Since video conversion works fine and stable with synchronous call (just ConvertMedia from Upload_Click handler) I may suggest the following reason: you've started conversion in new thread with `t1.Start()` but I don't see any code that waits for thread end. As result current request handling is finished but conversion thread may still run and raise ConvertProgress event (which may access objects of request that was already finished). Depending on situation (for example, asp.net app restart/recycle) conversion may crush with "attempted to access an unloaded appdomain" or other errors.

If you want to execute conversion process in background from asp.net application you may use [HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn636893%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (available only from .NET framework 4.5.2 or later) or organize your own background queue (for example create new "conversion task" in DB table and execute conversion by special worker implemented as Windows Service or Console app that periodically started with Windows Scheduler).

Comment: I am in the process of trying this right now about the QueueBackgroundWorkItem doesn't work...same error  :(