# .NET Threads are not separate?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, nreco

I have a sub which gets the duration of a video file.

```
Async Sub GetDuration(folder As String)

Dim ffP As New FFProbe
Dim vInfo As MediaInfo

Dim totalSecs As Double = Await Task.Run(Function()
                                           vInfo = ffP.GetMediaInfo(filep)
                                           If vInfo.Duration.TotalSeconds < 10
                                            Thread.Sleep(20000)
                                           End If
                                           Return vInfo.Duration.TotalSeconds
                                         End Function)
```

When I run this on a short video (less than 10 seconds), it sleeps the application for 20 seconds, as expected.  On another tab in the browser, however, I run it on a long video (greater than 10 seconds), while the first thread is still sleeping...but it sleeps, too, until the 20 seconds has expired/passed.  So both tabs are sleeping, which indicates to me that they are really the same thread.  Isn't VB.NET supposed to create separate threads when using the Async/Await pair?

The main idea was to have them run separately, so multiple users can get duration independently of each other.

Comment: Try doing `Await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20.0))` instead of `Thread.Sleep(20000)`.

Comment: So this is ASP.Net? If so and your using session state then requests within the same session will be serialized - i.e the request from the 2nd tab is queued by IIS until the 1st completes.

Comment: Thnx. How can I get it to create separate threads, then? (the idea was to have them run separately, so multiple users can get duration)

Comment: Multiple users will be in different sessions so this should not be an issue.  To test instead of using a 2nd tab use a new Private Browsing window or different browser & see if the same thing happens.

Comment: Take a look at this question: [If async-await doesn't create any additional threads, then how does it make applications responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37419572/if-async-await-doesnt-create-any-additional-threads-then-how-does-it-make-appl)

Comment: @AlexK.: you were right.  I tested it as you suggested.  I can get this done without threading at all since they're in different sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Async and await patterns are not multithreading. The same thread is used, but the processes in that thread are scheduled in a way so that the thread is not locked. In VS, you can inspect the threads you have running during debug.

Comment: Thnx.  How can I get it to create separate threads, then?  (the idea was to have them run separately, so multiple users can get duration)

Comment: I'm no expert at VB, but .net supports parallel operations. There should be a VB equivalent: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-use-parallel-invoke-to-execute-parallel-operations